# creating own titleize method

Tags: ruby, rspec

The following code passes an rspec test:

```
class Book

  attr_reader :title

    def initialize(title=nil)
      @title = title && title.capitalize!
    end

    def title=(new_title)
        @title = new_title && new_title.capitalize!
    end

end
```

I don't understand why, or this code at all for that matter..

1. attr_reader: I read that it makes an instance variable for the
   parameter passed(So @title) is this correct?
2. title && title.capitalize! : What is this doing?
3. title=(new_title) : Why is there an equal sign before the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def title=(new title)
```

is defining a method called title= which sets the instance variable to the parameter 'new_title'

This code:

```
@title = new_title && new_title.capitalize!
```

Will not call the capitalise function if new_title is nil.
So it is dealing with the case where nil is passed as a parameter without raising an exception by trying to call capitalise on it.

The exclamation mark indicates that the capitalise method modifies the new_title variable.